# Using user input to for if/else loops having trouble with totalPoint function if statement using input

Tags: python

Whenever I use 2 for input in the scoreShift funtion it displays ['>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int']

I know there is a problem with the totalPoint funtion in the if statement. That's primarily where
the issue is. I just cant figure out what the error message about means in this context.

```
#Message display description
print("This program reads exam/homework scores and reports your overall course grade.")

#Space
print()

#Title for Midterm 1
print("Midterm 1:")

#Prompt user for weight (1-100)
def weight():

    #Asking user for weight of assignment
    weight = int(input("Weight (0-100)? "))

    #Return the weight
    return weight

#User enters score
def scoreEarned():

    #Asking user for score earned on assignment, max score is 100
    scoreEarned = int(input("Score earned? "))

    #return score
    return scoreEarned

#Prompt user if scores were shifted
def scoreShift():

    #prompting user to input 1 for yes and 2 for no
    yesOrNo = int(input("Were scores shifted (1=yes, 2=no)? "))

    #if statement for if there is a score shift
    if(yesOrNo == 1):

        #prompt user for shift amount
        scoreShift = int(input("Shift amount? "))

        #return the shift of score
        return scoreShift
   

#display the total points out of 100, also cannot go over 100
def totalPoint():

    #variable for bottom half of fraction
    outOf = 100

    #going to display what was entered by user that might use the shift
    if (scoreShift > 0):#THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING TROUBLE

        #add score earned and score shift
        newTotalPoint = scoreEarned + scoreShift

        #if statment that will check to make sure points are not over 100 for total

        #display new total points
        print("Total points = ",newTotalPoint,"/",outOf)

    #else there is no shift score
    else:

        #Print the  score earned out of 100
        print("Total points = ",scoreEarned,"/",outOf)

weight()
scoreEarned()
scoreShift()
totalPoint()
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, `if (scoreShift > 0):` should be `if (scoreShift() > 0):`.

The reason is `scoreShift` is a function that needs to be called, so when you reference the variable `scoreShift`, you are actually referencing a function. Instead, you simply want to call the function with no arguments by adding the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you that helped me with understanding and I took a different approach.